# neo4j.v1.api.CypherError: Internal error - should have used fall back to execute query, but something went horribly wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j

Getting `neo4j.v1.api.CypherError: Internal error - should have used fall back to execute query, but something went horribly wrong` when using python neomodel client with neo4j community edition 3.2.0 server.

And the neo4j server logs has the below errors:

> 2017-05-16 12:54:24.187+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client
>   triggered an unexpected error [UnknownError]: Internal error - should
>   have used fall back to execute query, but something went horribly
>   wrong, reference 4c32d6e0-a66a-4db4-830c-b8d03ce6f1e3.
>
> 2017-05-16 12:54:24.187+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client
>   triggered an unexpected error [UnknownError]: Internal error - should
>   have used fall back to execute query, but something went horribly
>   wrong, reference 4c32d6e0-a66a-4db4-830c-b8d03ce6f1e3. Internal error
>   - should have used fall back to execute query, but something went horribly wrong
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ir.v3_2.exception.CantHandleQueryException:
>   Internal error - should have used fall back to execute query, but
>   something went horribly wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a issue with neo4j version 3.2.0. Setting `cypher.default_language_version` to `3.1` in neo4j.conf and restarting the server should fix this.